# how do i make session variables available through out all controllers and views in cakephp 3.2

Tags: cakephp-3.0

my login function in users controller

```
public function login() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        //   print_r($user);
        //            die();
        if ($user['role'] === 'student') {
            $this->Auth->setUser($user);
            $session = $this->request->session();
            $session->write('user', $user);
            return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'Useracountinfo/addinfo']);
        } elseif .....
```

and my add info function in the Useracountinfo

```
public function addinfo()
{
    $this->loadModel('Users');
    $userinfo= $this->Users->find('all');
    $session = $this->request->session();
    $userinfo = $session->read('user');
    //print_r($userinfo);
    //die();

    $this->set($userinfo);

    $user = $this->Useracountinfo->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $user = $this->Useracountinfo->patchEntity($userinfo, $this->request->data);
        print_r($user);
        die();
        if ($this->Useracountinfo->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('useracountinfo'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['useracountinfo']);
}`
```

and in my view i have something like this

```
<?php echo '<strong>'.$userinfo['email'].'</strong>'; ?>
```

Comment: what is exactly your issue?

Comment: i cant seem to accessing the session variables of the user i keep getting this error Notice (8): Undefined variable: userinfo [APP/Template\Useracountinfo\addinfo.ctp, line 198]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct syntax is (see the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#setting-view-variables))

```
$this->set('variable_name', somevalue);
```

so in your case

```
$this->set('userinfo', $userinfo);
```

mind that this is not a session variable but just a php variable that cake share from the controller to the view

if you want this to be available in every view you can do it in `AppController`

but you don't even need to do that because `$this->request->session()` is already always available in views too

This said I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve so maybe there are better solutions